# Can Mystique shapeshift into non-humanoid animals in the comics?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In *X-Men: Evolution*, Mystique is shown to shapeshift into a wolf and an eagle. The powers and abilities of characters have been a little different for many characters when jumping between mediums and continuities.

[image: Mystique as a wolf]

[image: Mystique as an eagle]

Excluding her ability to form clothes/accessories on her, does Mystique ever demonstrate the ability to shift into non-humanoid forms such as wolves or eagles (not humanoid aliens such as Kree, Skrulls, etc) in the comics?

Comment: Comicvine says not. "*As of yet Mystique has not demonstrated any ability to adopt the form of non-humanoid beings, animals, plants, or non-living objects, it is conjectured that she cannot imitate any of these without interfering with the proper functioning of her internal organs and possibly causing her death*";  http://www.comicvine.com/mystique/4005-1469/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes, although it has happened very rarely**

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_%28comics%29) notes that she can:

> Mystique is a mutant shapeshifter with the ability to psionically shift the formation of her biological cells at will to change her appearance and thereby assume the form of other humans and animals.

The reference is Astonishing X-Men #62.  The scene occurs as Mystique is leaving a resturant and doesn't want to be spotted - so for some reason instead of a random person, she shapeshifts into a dog:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the comics, the clearest example that she can is in *X-Factor* #134, which came out in 1997. In it, she transforms twice into large animal-like / monster-like forms pretty casually.

[image]

[image]