# Limits of Mystique's shapeshifting

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant, shape-shifter

I've read that Mystique can turn into animals and inanimate objects, but could she turn into something really small, like a bug?

What are the limits of her shapeshifting powers?

Comment: Possibly not a dupe, but very much related: [Can Mystique shapeshift into non-humanoid animals in the comics?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52885/can-mystique-shapeshift-into-non-humanoid-animals-in-the-comics).

Comment: Are you referring to any one version/continuity in particular?

Comment: Not really - but I heard her powers were advanced in the Evolution series?

Answer (score 3):

In *Days of Future Past*, there's a scene where Mystique infiltrates Bolivar Trask's office. She shapeshifts into the form of Trask, and it jumped out at me that Mystique was able to successfully pass as a dwarf.

Aside: as per Wikipedia, Peter Dinklage has a form of dwarfism, and I wanted to make sure I was using the right word.

Anyway, according to the movies, she can at least turn into people that are noticeably smaller than her. Off the top of my head, I can't remember any occasion in the comics that she shapeshifted into someone significantly larger (e.g., Apocalypse, Colossus, Hulk).