# Can Mystique shapeshift to someone who is considerably larger than herself?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Say someone like The Hulk? Or Galactus even?

Comment: This may already have been answered: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56952/how-does-mystique-change-height?rq=1

Comment: @Hans But that question asks about *how* her shapeshifting works, while this one is about whether she can shapeshift to someone larger.

Comment: Mystique can [create objects](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26705/5184) and [turn into animals](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/52885/5184). Being able to grow bigger/smaller doesn't seem like a far jump.

Answer (score -1):

Mystique is an infiltrator multimorph, her abilities are to impersonate others appareance, voice, manners, etc... but she doesn't replicate their combat skills or attributes.

I don't recall her morphing to anything not humanoid (a fly, a dog, a gorilla) which makes me think that she only can transform herself into normal humanoid forms, this should discard giants, titans, hulks and it's relatives.

Comment: Do you have support to go with your supposition?

Comment: The problem to demonstrate that she doesn't change to anything non humanoid is that, if I'm right, there's no possibility to demonstrate it. On the contrary, if I'm mistaken, anyone can show us a comic strip where she transforms to a fly or a dog...

Comment: The question is about size, and the querant's examples are humanoids, so the entire non-humanoid part of your answer is moot. I would be surprised if there wasn't a scene somewhere where she was asked "Can't you just..." and the answer was "No, no I can't." (Possibly followed by stabbing or neck snapping.)

Comment: The non-humanoid part, in fact, is relevant, because non-humanoids usually have in common an important difference in size with humanoids. Once again, if the scene you propose doesn't exist, I cannot demonstrate it anyway, but you can finish this discussion easily finding it and linking it here. What I'm doing in my answer is using a logic sequence. I've never seen her change to anything lesser or greater than a human (even when it'd be very useful quite often) --> I infer she's not able to do so --> I infer she isn't also able to transfer into a greater or lesser humanoid form.